# Email validation is not working in Laravel Form Validation

Tags: php, validation, email, laravel-5

I have tried almost every possibility but Email Validation is not working in form validation and it takes to MySQL exception of unique email required.

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
        'email'=>"required|email|unique:users,email",
        'password' => "required|min:6",
        'first_name' => "required",
        'last_name'=>"required",
        'country'=>"required",
        'city'=>"required",
        'is_willing_to_relocate'=>"required",
        'min_gross_salary'=>"required|integer|min:0",
        'max_gross_salary'=>"required|integer|min:0",
        'skills'=>'required|json|objCount',
        'languages'=>'required|json|objCount',
        'professions'=>'required|json|objCount',
        'cities'=>'required_if:is_willing_to_relocate,yes|json|objCount'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've made no changes to the standard User model attributes for email? Where are your two returns coming from? This is a horrible way to demonstrate your issue - there is no context given. You should provide the whole method definition. You may cut parts for brevity but always in the interest of providing the best context possible.

Comment: modified , i have two models candidates and users  . and this validation is for candidate when he signs up i create user too  based on email and password . . i am using form validation everything is working fine except email unique validation . .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate like this:

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users' ,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: i am using form validation